# processing image load error without inline-script

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

To process image load error I used to write something like this:

```
<img src="image.png" onError="this.src='defaultImage.png';"/>
```

but since I've added content-security-policy to my app, inline-scripts doesn't work anymore.

Are there any other solutions for this problem?

Comment: Is it specifically in-line scripts that don't work ? Could you attach the onError event using javascript afte rthe page has loaded ?

Comment: It's not so good solution because a lot of markup is generated by js, so it will not be handled on DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: I see - although .. could you add it after the event which generates the markup?

Comment: Certainly I can, but I have a lot of such places and I don't want to call some code each time I generate the markup. Solution should be more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reliable way to replace broken images in the browser, even the `onerror` attribute doesn't work in all major browsers ([compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Browser_compatibility)).

The proper and safe solution is to serve all images through a reverse-proxy, and configure it to send back a default image when the upstream request fails.

---

Related question: [jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images).